# Solve commit history issues with "git pull"

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub [repo](https://github.com/AwesomeCronk/Cubes) which I have been pushing to repeatedly from home and school. A few day ago, I was forced to reset my home PC and re-initialize that local repo. Now, whenever I try to pull to my school PC I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\ccronk22\Documents\Python\Cubes>git pull github master
From https://github.com/AwesomeCronk/Cubes
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

C:\Users\ccronk22\Documents\Python\Cubes>
```

Adding the -f or --force tags between pull and GitHub changes nothing. I am using git with Windows 10 CMD.

How do I pull changed to my school PC, then push it back to the remote, then pull/change/push on my home PC while stopping this mess?

Comment: Can you post us the tree which you get with gitk? That might help. Also give us the output of ```git branch```

Comment: You reset your home pc and you have problems with your school pc? Did you do anything with your github repo? I assume a step is missing? Did you force push the home pc repo to github? How did you "reinit"?

Comment: Given Tim Biegelisen's answer, I believe I managed to reset the history of my home PC's local repo. Then, when I pushed that to the GitHub repo, (I did have to force it.) I reset the history of the GitHub repo.

Comment: As a rule of thumb as a git learner: Never use git push --force. In my experience you only have to use it if something is screwed up or went wrong. And if that is the case be absolutely certain that where you are pushing to is the screwed up version and what you are pushing from is the correct version. So add-on to rule: use git push --force only to fix something that went wrong ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you arrived at this situation, but the error message indicates that your local Git repo contains a history which is unrelated to the remote repo to which it is pointing.  That is, most likely, your local and remote repos are different.  Assuming you don't have the problem of trying to save any local uncommitted work, the simplest fix here might be to just delete the project folder and clone again:

```
# from C:\Users\ccronk22\Documents\Python\
rm -r Cubes\
git clone <URL for Cubes project>
```

This approach will leave you with a new local project folder which is in sync with the latest remote.  It is suitable assuming you don't have any unversioned work locally.

Answer (score 1):

I would decide which repo is your current one with the history you want and see if you have any uncommitted changes in one of the others.

First save a copy of the folder of uncommitted changes on the pc that has them as a backup. If there are any.

Now depending which one is the most relevant you have to do the following:

**Easiest**: github is the relevant code and history:
Any repositories on the pcs that don't work just delete them and clone them again from github.

```
git clone <github>
```

**Second Option**: One of the pcs is relevant and github is NOT relevant:
ATTENTION: This will overwrite your github repo. Think about it twice if this is really necessary:

On the pc with the relevant code (assuming your github is called origin):

```
git push --force origin master
```

Then as in the first option delete the not working pc's git folder and clone again.

**If you have uncommitted changes** - only if relevant:
Once you corrected the repository on the pcs take the backup from the uncommitted changes and copy them into the newly cloned repository. Watch out not to overwrite .git, .gitattributes or .gitignore. Best would be to identify the changed files and only copy them. Then you can commit and push the changes as usual.

**Background on the error and how it can happen**
This can happen for example if you delete the .git folder on the home pc. Then you init the folder again as a git repository and git push --force to github. Then the other school pcs repository is not related to the github repository anymore. Because for git this is completely new and unrelated. Thats why you get a "unrelated history" error.

Answer (score 0):

You should clone the repo instead of reinitializing it.

pls use: git clone https://github.com/AwesomeCronk/Cubes.git

This will clone your history along as well and the unrelated history message should go away.